When I press the CTRL keys on my keyboard, all the keys in that row are pressed
Recently, when I'm pressing my Ctrl key on my Keychron V1 MAX, all the keys in a row with the Ctrl key are being pressed.
I have done a factory reset and it's still the same!

Assuming you meant Keychron, it would be a good idea to contact their user support. Is there any possibility that there was a liquid spill into the keyboard? That is the kind of thing that can cause that problem, but it may be easy to fix.

Can you be more precise describing what you mean when you say "it would registe the whole CTRL row keys"? Do you mean all the keys in a row with the CTRL keys are being pressed? Both CTRL keys are being pressed? Something else? Please EDIT your question to make it more clear.

@music2myear All the keys in a row with the CTRL keys are being pressed.

Then you will need to contact Keychron support regarding this.

There is a long thread on reddit related to this: "Second K8 firing entire row on right most buttons. What is going on and how can I fix it?"
